# Is there a way to make my standalone script, bound to a doc?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

What I would like to achieve is bounding my **standalone script** to one of my Google Docs.

The resource available at developers.google.com haven't helped me in this instance. However these are the links related to this topic:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone

I suspect 'No'.

---

At this current time I am only playing around using this api.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: You can publish an Apps Script bound to a Doc.  So, in that case, it's both bound, *and* published.  If it's published, you get a separate URL that can be used to do something like run `doGet()`, which in turn can serve HTML to the browser.  What is the experience that you are trying to create?

Comment: cut code from standalone, paste into bound script

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks for the reply. I was trying to do; `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` while in a standalone script yet obviously you are unable to do that because the document needs be bound. Yet it occurred to me 'what if' i wanted to use the standalone script in a bound one. It does seem that @Jonathon 's response is correct though but not ideal.

Comment: You can use the script from one script in another script file by using a "library".  Get the Project key from Project Properties, and use it in another script file.  Resources, libraries.  [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

Comment: @SandyGood Thanks. Again another great work around but at the cost of speed. "will not run as quickly". Again I think it's silly that there is no import functionality. Thanks again to all.

Comment: The slower speeds may not be an issue for lots of scripts.  If your script runs in 0.15 milliseconds, and then it goes up to 0.3 milliseconds, I don't think anyone will notice.  It might be a problem with processing lots of data, or like the documentation states, an Add-on.

Comment: You can "test as add-on", which will associate your script to a document or spreadsheet as if it was bound. I agree with Sandy, though... the small speed cost of a library is insignificant in most cases.

Comment: Hmm true. I'll definitely give it a try from those suggestions. I don't think 'speed' would become an issue but it's always worth noting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is; there is no way you can achieve a simple import form standalone to bound.

**But**

There are several work arounds, such as copying the code from the standalone to the bound one. Or via import methods mention by @Sandy Good

Thanks to all that helped.